# Learning, understanding and using algorithms

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, intuition

I am a 2nd year computer science student. We all have subjects about Data Structures, Theories, more more theories we all know that i have a subject this semester Design Analysis of Algorithms.

So my question is. How do you guys understand well all the Algorithms? Any technique?

To snap out the confusion about my question, I just want to know your techniques in learning algorithms. We all know that Algorithms is very important aside from the Programming stuffs and some students find it hard to understand and considered me sometimes ..... I don't have problems in Programming subjects (not boasting) but I excel in Programming and I'm very interested to dive deep in learning more about Algorithms. Some people don't think that Data Structures and Design Analysis of Algorithms an important subjects. But i do really think that learning more about Algorithms is a very efficient way in learning in programming too. So any answers will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Every program you write is an algorithm. If you excel at programming, you already excel at algorithms. (Or, put another way, if you're using bad algorithms, you're not excelling at programming.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer sir! But how do you understand well algorithms? And for you sir, what really is the purpose of this kind of subjects.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. This is a [questions and answers site](http://cs.stackexchange.com/tour), not a discussion forum. What you've posted here is a discussion starter, [not an answerable question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). (And even as a discussion starter I don't understand what you're after.)

Comment: I edited your question. The title was not precise enough, and you should watch more your syntax and style. There is still a missing word (see dots) that I was unable to guess. However, it is up to you to modify it so that it might be acceptable to the moderators by fitting better the rules for questions.

Comment: @Christian Practice, Practice, and more Practice! Buy books on algorithms and read them.  Buy books on math and read those too.  Do all the exercises!  That's what I do at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a 35 years old result in Logic (the [Curry-Howard
correspondance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence)) that states (simplifying a bit) that algorithms are
like (isomophic to) proofs. If you take the *specification* of a
program/algorithm such as, 
`Given a sequence of integer, give a sorted sequence of the same integers in ascending order`. This may be read as
the statement of a *theorem* 
`For any sequence of integer, there is a sequence that contains the same integers in ascending order`.  And any
algorithm meeting the specification will actually correspond to a
proof of the theorem.

Most professionnals will never be asked to use this correspondence (at least in the current state of the technology), but it does provide
some understanding of the programming process.

What this indicates is that to understand algorithms, you have to
inscribe them in a structured body of systematic knowledge, as much as
possible, as you would do for mathematics.  And mathematics does also
play a role. What matters is understanding the structural
underpinnings of the type of entities you are dealing with, so that
you have an organized vision of what can or cannot be done, when and
how. Note that some algorithms use other algorithms as components, exactly as
some theorems are used to prove others.

Or to put it another way, you can work programming and algorithmic
design exactly the same way you work on a mathematical problem. In
mathematics, you learn a collection of definitions and of theorems that
involve these definitions. Given a problem, you try to identify
structures or entities that meet the definitions you know, for both
hypothesis and conclusion, and you try to apply the theorems to get a
proof.

When given a programming problem, you do exactly the same: you try to
identify data structures or abstract types and programming structures
that would adequately represent the entities you are supposed to deal
with, and then you try to compose various algorithms (theorems) to
actually get the work done.

In mathematics, what matters in some cases is the proof technique
rather than, or as much as, the result. You sometimes have to reuse
the same proof technique in a different context. The same goes for
algorithms. If you understand how they are designed, you can use a
similar design for other algorithms, in situations where known one do
not exactly apply. So it is not just knowing algorithms that matters,
but much more understanding them, understanding what makes them tick
the right way.  And that is not always easy.  Some research
improvements in algorithms result precisely from trying to understand
the deep reasons that make some of them work the way they do. And
this often involve understanding mathematical structures.

More generally, understanding a mathematical theory is **not** rote
learning of a collection of definitions and theorems (though it
sometimes help for specific very technical aspects). It is getting an
overall, structural mental picture of the various aspects of the
theory and the ways they interact. The same goes for algorithms.
For example you may want to study and understand in a global way how
one can deal with graphs. The various algorithms may have relations.
Then, given a problem, you may recognize that part of it may be seen
as a graph problem, and deal with it accordingly.

This said, the world may be a somewhat simpler place for most
programmers.  But the more you understand, the better you do.

I would like to point out that this is not the only facet of
programming. Of course, a good program must use good algorithmics. But
it often is not enough. Style and architecture matter. Your program
must be easy to understand and maintain.  From a mathematics point of
view, this may correspond  to what is called an elegant proof.
The choice of the programming language may matter, as the choice of
the right notations may matter in mathematics.  But that is a bit
beyond your question.

I am sure there is a lot more to say.

Comment: This is the best answer! Thanks for clarifying this sir @babou! I just believe that understanding well or mastering algorithms is one way in proving that you are a real programmer. What i mean is anyone can code its easy to learn to program and to solve a machine problem is you need your self understanding at problems and that depends on your logic how you think. But not all do know the real algorithm. The theories(huffmans, greedy, etc) I believe that having a solid base of algorithmic knowledge and  techniques is one characteristics that separates truly skilled programmers than the novice.

Comment: @Christian. As I said, "mastering algorithms" is not exactly one way of being a
good programmer, it is one part of the way. One other part is
understanding programming structures, concepts and organization, such
as type systems, environments, scoping, modularity, programming
paradigms, etc. so as to choose adequately your programming languages
and to properly design the architecture of your systems. It is not all
as easy and intuitive as it might seem. Algorithms are the words of your
language, and programming concepts are the way you organize them into
meaningful sentences. Good luck.

Comment: Yes sir! I'm already have subjects programming languages too which we learn about different programming paradigms(imperative, object oriented, functional and Logical) paradigms. It really gets my interest! Although i've known Object Oriented in Java Functional and Logic gets my interest :) but anyways thank you for the answer sir! I really appreciate it and take note all what you've said! God bless!